# Refused to execute script from '..../angular.min.js' because its MIME type ('application/octet_stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type check

Tags: nginx, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

I saw several questions about this error, but not sure, for some websites, it works. same angular.js, same html.
Even on my localhost everything is working (even if content-type is application/octet_stream) but using other websites it doesn't (same Chrome...)

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` in the sites that don’t work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options

Comment: @BarryPollard That's exactly that. nginx configuration... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` HTTP Header configured in your web server then the browser will not be able to "sniff" content to guess what type it is so you must send it with the appropriate content-type.